# Hadoop: installation problems

Tags: hadoop

I have installed hadoop, I have set the JAVA_HOME, but still getting this error, why?

```
/opt/hadoop/2.5.1/sbin: $JAVA_HOME
-bash: /opt/java/6.0: Is a directory
/opt/hadoop/2.5.1/sbin: ./start-dfs.sh 
Starting namenodes on [localhost]
localhost: Error: JAVA_HOME is not set and could not be found.
localhost: Error: JAVA_HOME is not set and could not be found.
Starting secondary namenodes [0.0.0.0]
0.0.0.0: Error: JAVA_HOME is not set and could not be found.
/opt/hadoop/2.5.1/sbin:
```

If I try:

```
sh start-dfs.sh 
start-dfs.sh: 82: /opt/hadoop/2.5.1/sbin/../libexec/hadoop-config.sh: Syntax error: word unexpected (expecting ")")
```

Comment: Did you set JAVA_HOME at `$HADOOP_HOME/conf/hadoop-env.sh`, too?

Comment: add export $JAVA_HOME to the end of your .profile or .bash_profile , execute it with source .bash_profile and then start hadoop

Comment: you need to set JAVA_HOME in "yarn-env.sh" for hadoop 2.x This file can be found on the same path where you can see hadoop-env.sh under /etc/hadoop

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use bash and not sh to invoke the scripts. That solved my problem.

Answer (score 0):

Open the file `hadoop.env.sh` within `hadoop-xxx/etc/hadoop` and add the following line

```
JAVA_HOME = "address of java"
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to set Java Enviornment in .bashrc file. You may also need to update java_home value in hadoop.env.sh

Follow steps from my answer and your hadoop installation will go just fine : 
[[Problems with installing Hadoop on Ubuntu 12.04](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13337034/problems-with-installing-hadoop-on-ubuntu-12-04/33103153#33103153])